# Can't get if to use Object variable as parameter

Tags: python, class, object, if-statement

Okay, so this is my code:

```
class Alguien:
    def __init__(self, age, genre):
        self.age=age
        self.genre=genre

#ejercicio 1

def ejercicios():
    a=0
    personas=[object]*100
    contHombre=0
    contMujer=0
    mayEighteen=0
    while a<100:
        edad=randint(0,100)
        genero=randint(0,1)
        personas[a]=Alguien(edad, genero)
        if personas[a].genre==1:
            contHombre+=1
        elif personas[a].genre==0:
            contMujer+=1
        elif personas[a].age>18:
            mayEighteen+=1
        
        a+=1

    print(f"{mayEighteen}")

ejercicios()
```

I'm learning python, and I'm trying to use this class "Alguien" to set age and genre for a list of a hundred people. For some reason, it does recognize the value of genre in the If, but it doesn't recognize the value of age. This is the part of the code giving me problems:

```
elif personas[a].age>18:
    mayEighteen+=1

a+=1

print(f"{mayEighteen}")
```

Where personas[a].age will always be 0. Please help ^^

Comment: your second elif should really be an if :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elif` is only executed if the previous `if` and `elif` were false. Since either `genre == 1` or `genre == 0` will be true, it will never perform the `age > 18` test.

Use a separate `if` for that rather than `elif`.

You should also use `else:` instead of `elif` when the second condition is the opposite of the first.

```
def ejercicios():
    a=0
    personas=[]
    contHombre=0
    contMujer=0
    mayEighteen=0
    for a in range(100):
        edad=randint(0,100)
        genero=randint(0,1)
        personas.append(Alguien(edad, genero))
        if personas[a].genre==1:
            contHombre+=1
        else:
            contMujer+=1
        if personas[a].age>18:
            mayEighteen+=1
```